# Developing and Testing Annotation Processor for JDK 1.8

Tags: java, maven, annotations, maven-3, annotation-processing

I am developing an annotation processor for my project using `JDK1.8, Maven 3.6.3`

Current condition:

- I create an annotation processor (contain processor and some annotations) on separated project with the main project and packaged it as jar
- I register it to : `src/main/resource/META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor` of the processor project
- On the processor `pom.xml` file , I add `-proc:none` to the maven plugin compiler , as compiler argument,
  as so many lecture I found told me to do so,
- I include the processor jar as dependency(system scope) to the main project which is working fine,
  as all annotation I use is resolved
- And my processor is working in processing the annotation

Problem:

- Currently I can't try/test my annotation processor (incubated in the processor project),
  I always done with packaging it first then try/test it in the main project,

Question:

- Is there any solution, so I could test first my annotation processor before packaging it to my main project?
- Or am I wrong with something here? please tell me what to do

Thanks, really appreciate for any solution

Comment: Can you describe how you are testing right now, especially how you are running the maven compiler plugin? Changes are you just need to stop passing `-proc:none` to the test compile, as this is telling it to not run your processor for the test.

Comment: please note that i use -proc:none on the processor project, as i describe above, and it compiled successfully, as compiler didnt search for annotation processing. And then i use the jar created as dependency to main project in order to test it, and it works, the processor is working . The struggle is how to test it in the processor project itself. if i remove the -proc:none the processor project will always fail to compile, with message "Bad configuration file....."

Comment: You can use `compile-testing` to test your processor. Take a look here: https://github.com/NaluKit/nalu/tree/master/nalu-processor or here: https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt-editor/tree/master/gwt-editor-processor